# add variable to process_page($vars) in form function

Tags: forms, theming, 7

Is there an option to change $vars array in form function? I would like to pass some variables to page template in form creation function .. If not, what are other options to influence page.tpl from form?

EDIT:
I have a function for form creation and i would like to add page class if some params are sent to this function.

```
function mymodule_test_form($form, &$form_state, $param){
  if ($param == 'special'){
    #add class to page
  }
}
```

thanks!

Comment: I think you'll need to provide some more detail @gregab.  Your question is not very clear.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are talking about two different things: altering form fields vs. modifying the $variables array in page.tpl.php.

1) When you say "form creation function", what I hear is that you want to change fields in an existing form. For this, you would want to implement [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). If you want to learn more about how to structure a form, visit the [Form Generation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/group/form_api/7) page in the Drupal API.

2) If actually you meant that you want to add or change variables in your `page.tpl.php` file, then you'll want to implement [hook_preprocess_page()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want add some variable to prepared variables in `page.tpl.php`
for this job you should add it in you `template.php` file in your current theme.

create a function start with your theme name ,(as example if I use mytheme , it will be function `mytheme.preprocess_page`) , then add your variables to $variables array ( be sure that it passed by reference in function (&$variables) )

as example

```
function ThemeName_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

$variables['gregab'] = 'Hello,I am new variable :)';  
  }
```

//Part of Page.tpl.php Anywhere put this variable

print $gregab;

Then clear the cache (dont forget every time you change the 'tpl` files clear the caceh)

enjoy!